# tkz-tab: problem with tkzTabIma

Tags: tables, tkz-tab

how can i make the number 1 and 0 lie on the line at f(x) row

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please don't use screenshots for code, and provide a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Comment: FYI, the CTAN entry for this package states "This package has been taken temporarily out of circulation to give the author time to investigate some problems."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?
[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzTabInit
[lgt=2, espcl=0.009\linewidth] % tuy chon
{$x$/1, $f'(x)$/1, $f(x)$/2}{$-\infty$,1,2,$+\infty$}% hang 1 côt 2
\tkzTabLine{,+,5,-,7,-}% hang 2 côt 2
\tkzTabVar{- / $-\infty$, R/, R/, +/$-\infty$} % häng 3 côt 2
\tkzTabIma{1}{4}{2}{1}
\tkzTabIma{1}{4}{3}{0}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The `\tkzTabIma` lines need `{start}{end}{position}{value}`.
So in your case you have defined the arrow across four cells (from left to right), so you need `{1}{4}` at the start of each label.  Then `{1}{4}{2}{1}` gives you a "1" in cell 2, while `{1}{4}{3}{0}` gives you a "0" in cell 3.

Doing `texdoc tkz-tab` brings up the documentation, but it is in French (on my system).

Comment: tks u so much it worked!